# Gradle/Android: Specify 'root' as a dependency of subproject

Tags: gradle, android-studio

First of all, I've got an Android Studio project setup that works fine from within Studio. I can build it and run it on a device and in the emulator without problem and can also build a release APK.

I'm now trying to get to the point where I can have some command-line tools that will handle my build for me. All the reading I've done suggests that Android Studio uses gradle, but from what I've seen that's clearly not the case for my project -- as I had to create my build.gradle, settings.gradle files before gradlew would even attempt to build anything -- and yet Android Studio could still compile and deploy just fine.

Here's my project structure (as it sits physically on disk):

```
Root Project (Android library project, contains all the src, logic, UI, activities, etc.)
\--- WrapperProject (Android app, depends on the root project)
\--- SubProject1 (Android library, used by root)
\--- SubProject2 (Android library, used by root)
```

This is my root project's `settings.gradle` file

```
include ':SubProject1', ':SubProject2'
```

Likewise, here's my root project's `build.gradle` file. Note that this project is marked as an android-library and does not reference the WrapperProject in any way (should it?)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':SubProject1')
    compile project(':SubProject2')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

I'm able to build my root project successfully using `gradlew build` -- but my ultimate goal is to build the APK from the WrapperProject that has a dependency on the root project. Can you suggest what my WrapperProject's build.gradle file should contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm here because of searching for similar answers, although my problem is primarily the opposite. I'm finding that the integration between command-line builds (gradlew) and Android Studio 0.2.2 is full of secrets.

One thing I see that stands out in your config file: this is pretty beta/alpha stuff. You have not revised your project to the latest Android Studio 0.2.0 notes. In particular, the 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4' should be revised.  Reference: http://tools.android.com/recent

There is an open source application that has the same basic need as yours. It is a Grocery Shopping app that is provided as a sample for CouchDBLIte https://github.com/couchbaselabs/GrocerySync-Android

it has to reference the existing projects.  It seems to use a more explicit syntax for the dependencies than you did. example: "compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteEktorp:0.7.4'" - including the full class paths.  But they define two basic approaches, direct integration and artifact integration.

Sorry I can't provide a more precise answer to your syntax issue - but I'm sharing what I know so far.